# Spring Bean Validation @Valid handling

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have created a Spring MVC REST service using Bean Validation 1.2 with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valid")
public String validatedMethod(@Valid ValidObject object) {

}
```

If object isn't valid, Tomcat informs me that `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` and my `validatedMethod` is never called.

How can I get the message that was defined in the `ValidObject` bean? Should I use some filter or interceptor?

I know that I can rewrite like below, to get the set of `ConstraintViolation`s from the injected `Validator`, but the above seems more neat...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valid")
public String validatedMethod(ValidObject object) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<ValidObject>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(object);
    if (constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
        return "valid";
    } else {
        final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        constraintViolations.forEach((action) -> {
            message.append(action.getPropertyPath());
            message.append(": ");
            message.append(action.getMessage());
        });
        return message.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe a better way of doing this is using `ExceptionHandler`.

In your `Controller` you can write `ExceptionHandler` to handle different exceptions. Below is the code for the same:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationFailureResponse validationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    final List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

    return new ValidationFailureResponse((FieldError[])(fieldErrors.toArray(new FieldError[fieldErrors.size()])));
}
```

When you send a bad request to the Controller, the validator throws an exception of type `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. So the ideal way would be to write an exception handler to specifically handle this exception.

There you can create a beautiful response to tell the user of things which went wrong. 
I advocate this, because you have to write this just once and many `Controller` methods can use it. :)

**UPDATE**

When you use the @Valid annotation for a method argument in the `Controller`, the validator is invoked automatically and it tries to validate the object, if the object is invalid, it throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

If Spring finds an `ExceptionHandler` method for this exception it will execute the code inside this method.

You just need to make sure that the method above is present in your Controller.

Now there is another case when you have multiple `Controller`s where you want to validate the method arguments. In this case I suggest you to create a `ExceptionResolver` class and put this method there. Make your `Controller`s extend this class and your job is done.

Comment: Ok, this seems DRY. Could you elaborate a bit more? How do I wire this up to my `validatedMethod`? Oh, and the method is lacking a name.

Comment: `ValidationFailureResponse` seems to not be in any of my dependencies, and Google doesn't think it exists. Which Maven dependency could I add?

Comment: this is your custom response class. I said you can fabricate and send any response object you want :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57531/discussion-between-dormouse-and-dharam).

Comment: Referring to your update: You can now use `@ControllerAdvice` to define define global exception handlers.

Comment: Is there way I can produce the result of `Set<ConstraintViolation<ValidObject>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(object);` using `@Valid` in `MethodArgumentNotValidExeption` ?? I get only one field which is being voilated, but I want all of the fields which are voilated.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valid")
public String validatedMethod(@Valid ValidObject object, BindingResult result) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
    for (FieldError error : errors ) {
       builder.append(error.getField() + " : " + error.getDefaultMessage());
    } 
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Cheers, works like a charm :) Would be nice though, not having to do this for every validated method.

Answer (score 3):

When you use @Valid and doing bad request body Spring handle MethodArgumentNotValidException
You must create special class and extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and override handleMethodArgumentNotValid
Example

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(UserExistException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserExistException(
        UserExistException e, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    body.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    body.put("error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
    body.put("message", e.getMessage());
    body.put("path", request.getDescription(false).replace("uri=", ""));


    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    body.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    body.put("error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
    body.put("path", request.getDescription(false).replace("uri=", ""));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good addition. I use `@ControllerAdvice` for some time now, to avoid code duplication and to have all Exception based response handling in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @dharam works.
For users at Spring v4.3, Here's a nice implementation which uses a Custom Exception class to handle exception by type.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionClass extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
   @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, WebRequest req){
   // Build your custom response object and access the exception message using ex.getMessage()
}
}
```

This method will enable handling all `@Valid` exceptions across all of your `@Controller` methods in a consolidated way